# Is there a way to check if user is logged in using express.Router middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, routes

How can I insert `isLoggedIn` as a condition to the get request using router.route?

```
const controller = require('./controller');
const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  res.redirect('/');
}

router.route('/')
  .get((...args) => controller.find(...args))
```

I assume that the `...args` are (req, res, next)
I tried

```
router.route('/')
      .get(isLoggedIn(...args) => controller.find(...args))
```

But I get

```
.get((isLoggedIn(...args)) => controller.find(...args))
                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say, that you can assign multiple handlers to one route. Like this:

```
app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl)
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
  next()
})
```

[Source](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

In your case the coding looks like the following

```
router.get('/', isLoggedIn, controller.find);
```